# To count the first level child elements of any tag

Tags: jquery

```
$('.btns .next').click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass("di")) {what = "div";}
else{what = "img";}
...
var xlen = $(c).find('>' + what).length;
});
```

This counts the `first-level-children` in a `div`, and it works but is there a way to say:

```
var xlen = $(c).find('> whatever_is_first_child_of_c' ).length;
```

So, whether the first-child is `img` or `div` or `p` or anything - I need to count them.

Comment: everything works. thanks a lot. solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.wrapper >') // where wrapper is container or parent element
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the tag type of the first child and then perform the count operation:

```
var tagType = $(c).find(">:first-child").prop("tagName").toLowerCase(); // prop("tagName") returns capitalized value
var xlen = $(c).find('> '+tagType).length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) do the trick?

```
// number of direct descendants
var xlen = $(c).children().length;
```

You can even limit those to another selector:

```
// sum of total direct div, img and p descendants
var xlen = $(c).children('div, img, p').length;
```